# Mathematical symbol and name for Symbolic Replacement

Tags: replacement, symbolic

> (Originally from [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298486/mathematical-symbol-for-symbolic-replacement), but might be better here)

I'm searching for a mathematical symbol, that describes the symbolic replacement done for instance in Mathematica:

`f[xx_, a_, b_] := 3*xx /. {a -> b}
(* f[3*a*b, a, d]  gives 9 b d *)`

or

`g[exp_] := exp /. {a_[n_] -> a[-n + 2]}
(* g[3 b[3 + m]^2] gives 3 b[-1 - m]^2 *)`

Is there a mathematical symbol and term to describe such transformations (which is denoted as `/.` + a substituation list with `{ someA -> someB }` in Mathematica)?

PS: I see that there are two things I use here. First, the mathematica-functions `f[xx_, a_, b_]` and `g[exp_]` seem to be [functionals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_%28mathematics%29) (their arguments are functions). And then, there are those symbolic replacement operations denoted by `/. { someA -> someB}`. I am interested in the mathematically correct name for the second part. Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite think I've seen any words other than "substitution" and "replacement" being used, even in a mathematical context.

Comment: Re: notation, in some contexts, you'll see things like $$f^\prime(a)=\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)\right|_{x=a}$$ which indicate substitution; if there isn't a general one, maybe you can adapt this to what you have.

Comment: Thanks @J.M. That is actually a very good example, I haven't thought about that. I'll try whether all of my methods can be translated in such a way.

Comment: @J.M. I suppose it is the only part of SE where this is on topic. What do you think about moving your comment to answer?